# wordpress acf get_field('value') return empty

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am using acf to add some product custom fields on product tab. I have added regions. And now i need to display these regions on a dropdown on my vendor dashboard(For multivendor i use dokan). The problem is

```
<?php $regions = get_field('regions'); ?>
<pre> <?php print_r($regions); ?> </pre>
```

This code return me nothing. This is where i have added this code

```
<div class="product-full-container">

                    <?php
                        $data = Helper::get_saved_products_category();
                        $data['from'] = 'new_product_popup';
                        dokan_get_template_part( 'products/dokan-category-header-ui', '', $data );
                    ?>

                    
                    
                    <div class="dokan-form-group">
                        <?php $regions = get_field('regions'); ?>
                        <pre> <?php print_r($regions); ?> </pre>
                        <label for="regions"><?php esc_html_e( 'Region', 'your-text-domain' ); ?></label>
                        <select name="regions">
                            <option value=""><?php esc_html_e( 'Select Region', 'your-text-domain' ); ?></option>
                            <?php foreach ( $regions as $region ) { ?>
                                <option value="<?php echo esc_attr( $region['region_name'] ); ?>"><?php echo esc_html( $region['region_name'] ); ?></option>
                            <?php } ?>
                        </select>
                    </div>  


                    <?php do_action( 'dokan_new_product_after_product_tags' ); ?>

                    <div class="dokan-form-group">
                        <textarea name="post_excerpt" id="" class="dokan-form-control" rows="5" placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Enter some short description about this product...' , 'dokan-lite' ) ?>"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </d>
```

path of this file `/wp-content/plugins/dokan-lite/templates/products/tmpl-add-product-popup.php`

ANy idea how to fix this?

`Note`: What i am trying to do, is to add regions on vendor dashboard so they can select regions where theny need to publish theyr product

[UPDATED]
I have changed method to this.

```
<div class="dokan-form-group">
                    
                        <?php
                            $regions = get_terms([
                                'hierarchical' => 1,
                                'show_option_none' => '',
                                'hide_empty' => 0,
                                'taxonomy' => 'region'
                            ]);    
                        ?>

                         <!-- <?php    foreach ($regions as $region) { ?> -->
                            <!-- <pre> <?php print_r($regions) ?> </pre> -->
                        <!-- <?php    } ?> -->

                        <label for="regions"><?php esc_html_e( 'Region', 'your-text-domain' ); ?></label></br>
                        <select name="regions" class="dokan-form-control">
                            <option value=""><?php esc_html_e( 'Select Region', 'your-text-domain' ); ?></option>
                            <optgroup label="Piemonte">
                                <?php foreach ( $regions as $region ) { ?>
                                    <option value="<?php echo $region->term_taxonomy_id ?>" id="in-region-<?php echo $region->term_taxonomy_id ?>"> <?php echo $region->name ?> </option>
                                <?php } ?>
                            </optgroup>
                        </select>

                    </div>  <div class="dokan-form-group">
                    
                        <?php
                            $regions = get_terms([
                                'hierarchical' => 1,
                                'show_option_none' => '',
                                'hide_empty' => 0,
                                'taxonomy' => 'region'
                            ]);    
                        ?>

                         <!-- <?php    foreach ($regions as $region) { ?> -->
                            <!-- <pre> <?php print_r($regions) ?> </pre> -->
                        <!-- <?php    } ?> -->

                        <label for="regions"><?php esc_html_e( 'Region', 'your-text-domain' ); ?></label></br>
                        <select name="regions" class="dokan-form-control">
                            <option value=""><?php esc_html_e( 'Select Region', 'your-text-domain' ); ?></option>
                            <optgroup label="Piemonte">
                                <?php foreach ( $regions as $region ) { ?>
                                    <option value="<?php echo $region->term_taxonomy_id ?>" id="in-region-<?php echo $region->term_taxonomy_id ?>"> <?php echo $region->name ?> </option>
                                <?php } ?>
                            </optgroup>
                        </select>

                    </div>
```

And this work, i see all regions i have added by acf on products. But now i have another problem , when i create new product by dokan vendor dashboard it does not save region i select, also i dont know how to save on db . Any help?

Comment: Is the field correctly registered in ACF? And i believe `get_field()` only returns it if it has a value connected to that post. https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/ not really if you set up a function for all that. Isn't it then `get_fields()`. Sorry it's been a while.

Comment: I found another solution. Witch is `<?php
                            $regions = get_terms([
                                'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
                                'hide_empty' => false,
                            ]);    
                        ?>` but also this is show me all product type. Not only for regions

Comment: You should select then within the taxonomy your region taxonomy, or if you wanna move quickly, grab the `get_terms_field()` function to get your name quickly in the dropdown.

Comment: I have just updated my questions, can you help me with this?